# Using 'cat" to filenames with spaces in them

Tags: macos, shell, rsync

I'd like to replace 'cat' here so that line items in the source can have spaces, to make this Rsync script more portable (in OSX).

Can you experts please suggest ways to do this? Other suggestions to improve this are also appreciated! Thanks!

Dan

```
#!/bin/bash       
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin export PATH

LOG="/Users/jdoe/Desktop/rsync-`/bin/date +%m%d%Y`.log"
EXCLUDE="/tmp/exclude.dat"


{
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "Start:" $0
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
date "+%a %m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S" 
echo "-----------------------------------------------"

options="-aNHxEh --delete --fileflags --exclude-from=$EXCLUDE --delete-excluded --force-change --progress --stats --protect-args"

destin='/Users/jdoe/Desktop/DEST/'

for source in $(cat /tmp/list.dat)
  do

   echo "Source:      " $source
   echo "Destination: " $destin

   echo "rsync" $options $source $destin
   /opt/local/bin/rsync $options $source $destin

   retcode=$?
      if [ $retcode -gt 0 ]
              then
                 echo "ERROR: rsync " $source "failed with code " $retcode
              fi

echo "-----------------------------------------------"
date "+%a %m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S"
echo "-----------------------------------------------"

done

echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "End:" $0
echo "-----------------------------------------------"

} >> $LOG 2>&1


exit 0
```

Comment: Consider using an array to hold your options: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 -- as soon as things get slightly more complicated, you'll start to break down otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that's an excellent suggestion and one I've just implemented. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `cat`; use a `while` loop with `read`:

```
while read -r source; do
    echo "Source:      $source"
    echo "Destination: $destin"
    echo "rsync" $options $source $destin
    if ! /opt/local/bin/rsync $options "$source" "$destin"; then
        echo "ERROR: rsync $source failed with code $?"
    fi

    echo "-----------------------------------------------"
    date "+%a %m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S"
    echo "-----------------------------------------------"

done < /tmp/list.dat
```

Comment: Ah, that seems to work now. Thank you! I had the 'done' in the wrong place...Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the filename in quotes:

```
cat "/tmp/path/file with spaces.txt"
```

Similarly, when you do rsync:

```
rsync $options "$source" "$destin"
```

Quotes are always a good idea.

Comment: I think he's asking about file names contained in `/tmp/list.dat` having spaces, not the name of the file being read.

Comment: Ah. Well, he'll still need quotes around `$source` in his `rsync`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the finished, working script for those interested:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin export PATH

EMAILSUBJ="Rsync Results"
EMAILRECIP="admin@example.com"
EMAILSENDER="admin@example.com"
LOG="/Users/jdoe/Desktop/rsync-`/bin/date +%m%d%Y`.log"
EXCLUDELIST="/tmp/exclude.dat"
SOURCEFILE="/tmp/list.dat"
DESTINATION='/Users/jdoe/Desktop/DEST/'
RSYNC=/opt/local/bin/rsync
# Rsync options below:
ROPTIONS=(
    -aNHxEh
    --delete 
    --fileflags 
    --exclude-from=$EXCLUDELIST 
    --delete-excluded 
    --force-change 
    --stats 
    --protect-args
    )
# Get started
{
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "Start:" $0
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
date "+%a %m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S" 
echo "-----------------------------------------------"

while IFS= read -r SOURCE; do


   echo "SOURCE: $SOURCE"
   echo "DESTINATION: $DESTINATION"

   echo "rsync" "${ROPTIONS[@]}" $SOURCE $DESTINATION
   $RSYNC "${ROPTIONS[@]}" "$SOURCE" "$DESTINATION"

  RETCODE=$?
      if [ $RETCODE -gt 0 ]
              then
                 echo " "
                 echo "##########################################################"
                 echo "ERROR: rsync " $SOURCE "FAILED with code " $RETCODE
                 echo "##########################################################"
                 echo " "
              fi

echo "-----------------------------------------------"
date "+%a %m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S"
echo "-----------------------------------------------"

done < $SOURCEFILE                                       

echo "-----------------------------------------------"
echo "End:" $0
echo "-----------------------------------------------"



} >> $LOG 2>&1

# Send an email
(
echo "From: $EMAILSENDER"
echo "To: $EMAILRECIP"
echo "Subject: $EMAILSUBJ"
cat $LOG

) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -it 

exit 0
```